# "React Hook is called conditionally": How to check for optional contexts in a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, formik

I have a reusable custom input component that may or may not be used in a Formik context (i.e. either in a Formik form or outside of it generally). The behavior needs to be different accordingly. I need to determine the mode in this component. There is a hook called `useFormikContext()` that will throw an error if it's not applicable. But when I do

```
try {
    const { values, setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();
}
catch (error) {
    alert('NOT in the Formik Context');
}
finally {
    alert ('End');
}
```

I get

```
  Line 17:43:  React Hook "useFormikContext" is called conditionally. 
  React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

So is there a way to figure out cleanly whether I can apply the hook or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply don't destructure from the hook and check if the incoming value is `undefined` or not to perform your logic like so :-

```
 const formik = useFormikContext();
  if (!formik) {
    alert("NOT in the Formik Context");
  } else {
    alert("In the formik context");
  }
```

Here is the codesandbox :-

[image: Edit Formik - hook]

Though I would suggest to show throw a custom error in the if/else conditions and catch this error in a **Error Boundary** and then have a fallback component to show the error instead of using an `alert` if it's a UI thing to portray. Otherwise, skip the Error Boundary and alert thing altogether since `console.warn` logs are better for this.

Comment: Yeah, this solution is perfect if values itself is undefined otherwise use as I stated if values is defined but it's value is undefined.

Comment: thanks, this works - never mind about another comment I made.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your part to FC and then render with the condition.